# What test would I use on this series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_k \frac {k^2+2k+1}{3k^2+1}$$

No idea what test to use on this series.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test

Comment: Divergence test.

Answer (score 13):

Hint. A necessary condition for convergence of a series is that the term  should tend to zero. In your case, as $k\to +\infty$,
$$\frac {k^2+2k+1}{3k^2+1}=\frac {1+\frac{2}{k}+\frac{1}{k^2}}{3+ \frac{1}{k^2}}\to \frac{1}{3}.$$